# Django: is it possible to have model's FK linked to through model's PK to have one-to-many relationship?

Tags: django

I will have 2 models (Project and User) linked with a many-to-many relationship.

Django will create implicit through model with id, and the 2 FK (Project and User).

Is it possible to have a third models Application linked to the through model?

Can I declare a FK in Application that is linked to the through model id?

EDIT:

**forms.py**

```
NAME = Thesaurus.options_list(2,'fr')
ACCESS = Thesaurus.options_list(3,'fr') 
ApplicationFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Utilisateur, Application, 
    fields=('app_app_nom','app_dro'),
    widgets={
        'app_app_nom': forms.Select(choices=NAME), # name in Application model
        'app_dro': forms.Select(choices=ACCESS) # access_right in Application model
    },
    extra=3,
    can_delete=True,
)
```

**views.py**

```
class UtilisateurCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Utilisateur
    fields = ['uti_nom','uti_pre','uti_mai','uti_sit','uti_pro']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data["utilisateur"] = self.request.user.username # nom de l'utilisateur connecté
            data["projet"] = get_object_or_404(Projet, pro_ide = self.request.GET['projet'])
            data["application"] = ApplicationFormset(self.request.POST)
            data["user_profil"] = self.request.session.get('user_profil')
        else:
            data["application"] = ApplicationFormset()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        application = context["application"]
        user_profil = context["user_profil"]
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.pro_ide = context["projet"]
        self.object.uti_log = context["utilisateur"]
        self.object.uti_val = 0 
        self.object.uti_val_dat = timezone.now()
        self.object.save()

        if application.is_valid():
            application.instance = self.object
            application.save()

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("project:index")
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can add as many extra fields of whatever type. If however two `ForeignKey`s link to the same model, and the `ManyToMany` spans over that model, then you will need to specify which of the `ForeignKey`s is part of the m2m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I declare a FK in Application that is linked to the through model id?

**Yes**, you can add as many extra fields of any type you want. It is of course necessary to declare two `ForeignKey`s that refer to the "source" and "target" model in your `ManyToManyField`.

A specific situation that might require some extra work if you have two `ForeignKey`s to a same model, and that model "participates" in the `ManyToManyField`. In that case, Django does not know which of the `ForeignKey`s should be picked. In that case (only in that case) you *have* to specify the name of the foreign keys through the [**`through_fields=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields), which is a 2-tuple that specifies the names of the foreign keys to the "source" model and the "target" model respectively. This is described in the documentation, for example with:

> ```
> class Person(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
>
> class Group(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
>     members = models.ManyToManyField(
>         Person,
>         through='Membership',
>         through_fields=('group', 'person'),
>     )
>
> class Membership(models.Model):
>     group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>     person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>     inviter = models.ForeignKey(
>         Person,
>         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
>         related_name="membership_invites",
>     )
>     invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
> ```

But in your case, it is just another model, so then there is no confusion. You thus can define a model for example with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='UserProject'
    )

class Application(models.Model):
    # …

class UserProject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Based on that, I need to define how forms will look like. I need to display a list of projects and add users and applications that user can access. p.s.: the user table I talk about is not the auth_user model

Comment: @SLATER: I think you will need to make an `InlineFormSet` with the `through` model as model for the inline form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: Yes that I've done previously but my ER diagram were false: Project 1 ---- n User 1 ---- n Application

Comment: @SLATER: but based on your diagram, you do not want a `ForeignKey` from `UserProject` to application, but one from `Application` to `UserProject`, since it is a one-to-many from the `UserProject` side.